# Amplify React build fail with "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/...' in '/codebuild/output/src313005886/src/client-portal/src' "

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-amplify

for some time, I have been wrapping my head around an error preventing me from deploying my react app to AWS Amplify. The compiler seems not to be able to resolve a component during the build phase. I keep getting the following error `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/...' in '/codebuild/output/src313005886/src/client-portal/src`; please see the attached error output bellow.

[image]

Here is the file structure:

[image]

Here is how the file is imported:

`import AdminCreateEvaluation from "./components/evaluationgeneratorform";`

I have tried several solutions, including renaming my files, but the build won't just compile;
Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I've been receiving the same error as of recently. After adding Amplify backend to the React app, it no longer deploys and fails with a similar error.

"Failed to compile. Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/ResponsiveDrawer'" - Did you find anything since posting?

Comment: Similar issue here my build fails with: Failed to compile.
2022-05-04T13:58:33.330Z [INFO]: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws-amplify' in '/codebuild/output/src{some number...}/src/{some project...}/src'

Answer (score 4):

Check if you have changed the "Components" from uppercase to lowercase "components". In my case, I changed it after it had been created on GitHub. But GitHub doesn't update this change. When it's cloned to Amplify host, it's still "Components", so the build failed.

I had to change the name to something else and then change it back to fix the issue.

Comment: This solved my issue with `app.tsx`. Thanmks :)